# Why are Ctrl+a and Ctrl+f broken in Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, terminal

In most text areas, ctrl-a and ctrl-f used to move my cursor to the beginning/end of the line, but now I get "^A" printed to terminal, and nothing happens in other input areas.

Any ideas what happened?

Comment: So, the move is broken in textedit too? CTRL-A beginnig of line, CTRL-E end of line, CTRL-F one char right, CTRL-B one char left.

Comment: hmm, works in textedit, must be my bash key bindings

Comment: I also have it broken (OS-X Lion Preview4) but I don't have any "set -o vi" settings. Ctrl-A does not have any effect! WTF? I cannot use screen to switch or create new screen sessions.

Answer (score 2):

It was my bash key bindings - I had "set -o vi" in .bashrc.

Comment: So use, ESC-0 for the beginning of the line, "$" to end, and so on... :) but, you probably know "vi" when activated the vi-mode ;) (i'm using it too) :)

Comment: indeed - just overlooked that I would lose the emacs-style bindings :)